# Compile time error: ambiguous on calling overloaded method. Why?

Tags: java

For the code below, why do I get this compile time error:

The method overloadedMethod(IOException) is ambiguous for the type Test.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.overloadedMethod(null);

    }

    void overloadedMethod(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("1");
    }

    void overloadedMethod(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("2");
    }

    void overloadedMethod(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("3");
    }

    void overloadedMethod(ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("4");
    }

}
```

Comment: try removing void overloadedMethod(Exception e) { System.out.println("3");   } or commenting this?

Comment: @AtulOHolic yes I know that it will compile, but I am searching for the reason why I get this error when I added that method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `FileNotFoundException` and `ArithmeticException` are in the same level in java object hierarchy. Compiler confused to choose most specific method, Since both method are eligible for invocation.

Even Compiler can't choose most specific method, if there are multiple object hierarchies. So removing either of `FileNotFoundException` or `ArithmeticException` won't solve the problem.

From [JLS 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than
>   another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed
>   on to the other one without a compile-time type error.

Comment: Note that removing one of them won't solve the problem because of `IOException`.

Comment: `java.lang.Object -> java.lang.Throwable -> java.lang.Exception -> java.lang.RuntimeException -> java.lang.ArithmeticException`

Comment: `java.lang.Object -> java.lang.Throwable -> java.lang.Exception -> java.io.IOException -> java.io.FileNotFoundException`

Comment: @Vishrant : Yes, Answer updated. Compiler can't choose, if there are multiple hierarchies.

Comment: `java.lang.Object -> java.lang.Throwable -> java.lang.Exception -> java.io.IOException -> java.io.FileNotFoundException`

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan yes if I comment `void overloadedMethod(FileNotFoundException e)` then also compile time error for `void overloadedMethod(IOException e)`

Comment: @Vishrant : Yes, Because, even you commented out `FileNotFoundException` method, there are two hierarchies. Compiler can't choose.

Answer (score 1):

You have four versions of `overloadedMethod` that accept parameters of type `IOException`, `FileNotFoundException`, `Exception` and `ArithmeticException`.

When you call

```
test.overloadedMethod(null);
```

the JVM cannot know which version of the method you are intending to call. That is why the `ambiguous` error.

You need to be more specific on which version you want to call. You can do that by casting the parameter:

```
test.overloadedMethod((IOException)null);
```

Comment: Your first paragraph is incorrect. An `Exception` is not permitted for a method that expects an `IOException`.

Comment: @Duncan I am not sure I understand. Do you mean that if there is a method that accepts `Exception`, there cannot be an overloaded version that accepts `IOException`?